# create an empty scan function

Tags: ruby, file

How do I create a empty scan function? This is my `lexicon.rb` file

```
    require 'ex48/lexicon.rb'
    require "test/unit"

    class TestNAME < Test::Unit::TestCase
      def test_directions()
        assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("north"), [['direction', 'north']])
        result = Lexicon.scan("north south east")

        assert_equal(result, [['direction', 'north'],
               ['direction', 'south'],
               ['direction', 'east']])
      end

      def test_verbs()
        assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("go"), [['verb', 'go']])
        result = Lexicon.scan("go kill eat")
        assert_equal(result, [['verb', 'go'],
               ['verb', 'kill'],
               ['verb', 'eat']])
      end


      def test_stops()
        assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("the"), [['stop', 'the']])
        result = Lexicon.scan("the in of")
        assert_equal(result, [['stop', 'the'],
               ['stop', 'in'],
               ['stop', 'of']])
      end


      def test_nouns()
       assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("bear"), [['noun', 'bear']])
       result = Lexicon.scan("bear princess")
       assert_equal(result, [['noun', 'bear'],
               ['noun', 'princess']])
      end

      def test_numbers()
        assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("1234"), [['number', 1234]])
        result = Lexicon.scan("3 91234")
        assert_equal(result, [['number', 3],
               ['number', 91234]])
      end


      def test_errors()
        assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("ASDFADFASDF"), [['error', 'ASDFADFASDF']])
        result = Lexicon.scan("bear IAS princess")
        assert_equal(result, [['noun', 'bear'],
               ['error', 'IAS'],
               ['noun', 'princess']])
      end

    end
```

Here is the steps:

1. Write the require at the top. Get that to work.
2. Create an empty version of the first test case test_directions. Make sure that runs.
3. Write the first line of the test_directions test case. Make it fail.
4. Go to the `lexicon.rb` file, create an empty scan function.
5. Run the test, make sure scan is at least running, even though it fails.
6. Fill in psuedo code comments for how scan should work to make test_directions pass.
7. Write the code that matches the comments until test_directions passes.
8. Go back to test_directions and write the rest of the lines.
9. Back to scan in lexicon.rb and work on it to make this new test code pass.
10. Once you've done that you have your first passing test, and you move on to the next test.

Anyways, how do I create an empty scan function? Any answers is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function is

```
    def
      (your code)
    end
```

so a scan function is

```
    def
      scan ()
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

add the code

```
     def
      scan()
     end
```

Answer (score 1):

def scan 
end

Adding above function into the file.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a `SyntaxError`, you need either a linebreak, a semicolon or parentheses to tell Ruby that there's no parameter list.

Comment: ...plus `scan` needs to be changed to `self.scan` (because it's a class method) and the line needs to be wrapped in `class Lexicon`/`end`. Other than that, and the mistake @JörgWMittag noted, it's fine.

Comment: you should add '()' after scan

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'ex48/lexicon.rb'
require "test/unit"

class TestNAME < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_directions()
    assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("north"), [['direction', 'north']])
    result = Lexicon.scan("north south east")

    assert_equal(result, [['direction', 'north'],
           ['direction', 'south'],
           ['direction', 'east']])
  end

  def test_verbs()
    assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("go"), [['verb', 'go']])
    result = Lexicon.scan("go kill eat")
    assert_equal(result, [['verb', 'go'],
           ['verb', 'kill'],
           ['verb', 'eat']])
  end


  def test_stops()
    assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("the"), [['stop', 'the']])
    result = Lexicon.scan("the in of")
    assert_equal(result, [['stop', 'the'],
           ['stop', 'in'],
           ['stop', 'of']])
  end


  def test_nouns()
   assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("bear"), [['noun', 'bear']])
   result = Lexicon.scan("bear princess")
   assert_equal(result, [['noun', 'bear'],
           ['noun', 'princess']])
  end

  def test_numbers()
    assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("1234"), [['number', 1234]])
    result = Lexicon.scan("3 91234")
    assert_equal(result, [['number', 3],
           ['number', 91234]])
  end


  def test_errors()
    assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("ASDFADFASDF"), [['error', 'ASDFADFASDF']])
    result = Lexicon.scan("bear IAS princess")
    assert_equal(result, [['noun', 'bear'],
           ['error', 'IAS'],
           ['noun', 'princess']])
  end
   def scan()
   end

end
```

I figured it out. I did add

```
      def 
       scan()
      end
```

Comment: If you were to add `def scan() end` to your `Lexicon` class, your code would still work, because that (instance) method would never be called.

Comment: Yes, that's the main thing, especially when you've struggled with a problem for awhile. You could use a break now, so go, kill, eat!

Answer (score 1):

add 
def scan() end
Hopes it help